# Serializing floats/ doubles in C++, compiled to WebAssembly

Tags: c++, serialization, floating-point, ieee-754, webassembly

I am trying to serialize IEEE 754 floats/ doubles to byte arrays in my C++ code that is then compiled to WebAssembly. (This code then runs as an eosio smart contract, but I believe that this shouldn't be relevant)

My problem is that every solution I find that works in C++ doesn't work anymore after compiling it to WebAssemby, giving me the error `cause: access violation\n${callstack}`

I have tried *union*s, *reinterpret_cast* and *memcpy*, all of which gave me the error seen above. I don't really understand how Webassembly works, but my educated guess would be that Webassembly doesn't allow direct memory access like C++ does, and therefore there is no proper way for the compiler to translate the "standard" C++ solutions.

Do you know of any way to solve this problem. Are there perhaps C++ libraries that serialize arrays without using any solutions that directly access the memory? And if there aren't, do you perhaps have any ideas as to how you would solve this problem?

Comment: A simple code sample demonstrating the issue would most likely be helpful in getting a cogent answer to your question.

Comment: technically C++ standard doesn't allow all that (except memcpy), so implementation is allowed to be stubborn. C++ doesn't "allow direct memory access", actually ti works with memory model abstraction called "storage"

Comment: Simplest - althtough not most efficient - portable way to serialise floats is to convert them to strings (use scientific notation). I would expect that to work in webasm. We cannot tell what's wrong with your code if we don't know your code.

Comment: I ran this memcpy test in both gcc and emcc + node, and they produced the same output: https://godbolt.org/z/JJ3oKF

Comment: Can't fix code we can't see. Present a [mcve].

Comment: @eerorika: Decimal scientific notation is not a portable way to serialize floating-point values because the C and C++ implementations do not require identical rounding between implementations. If the floating-point radix is a multiple of 2, then the `printf` specifier `%a` or the `hextfloat` manipulator provide a portable serialization, since the conversions are required to be correct. They are also computationally easier than decimal scientific conversions and so are better for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors actually had nothing to do with the float/ double serialization but rather with the string to float/ double functions, which produce this error.